# Python - Format fixed length with data coming from a Excel

Tags: python, excel, formatting, zero, data-transfer

I am pulling data from a spreadsheet and one of the columns has leading zeroes. The zeros get trimmed when the data comes in. I need the preceding zeroes for the data transfer. Also, I need the format to always be four-digits.

Note: This example is distilled for simplification

For example:

**Spreadsheet**

| lastname | firstname | id_number | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| smith | john | 0008 | test |
| jones | sally | 0123 | test |
| baggins | bilbo | 4787 | test |

**Python code:**

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.descriptors.base import String

wrkbk = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\Philomathean\Desktop\Temp\ID.xlsx")

ws = wrkbk.active

rows = ws.iter_rows()

for LastName, FirstName, ID, Notes in rows:
    result = (f"The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: '{ID.value}'")
    f = open("C:\\Users\\CPRITCHARD\\Desktop\\Temp\\Example.txt", "a")
    f.write(f'{result}\n')
    f.close()
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

1. The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: **'0008'**
2. The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: **'0123'**
3. The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: **'4787'**

**ACTUAL RESULTS:**

1. The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: **'8'**
2. The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: **'28'**
3. The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: **'62'**

Comment: Try `'{ID.value:04d}'` **;-)** Read: [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: That worked. You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether `ID.value` is a string or integer. If it is an integer:

`result = (f"The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: '{ID.value:04d}'")`

If it is a string:

`result = (f"The ID should be 4 digits with leading zeroes for less than four digits: '{ID.value.zfill(4)}'")`